# "No such file or directory" protoc

Tags: go, grpc, protoc

The protofiles are located here `E:\GolangTr\GRPC\internal\protofiles\chat.proto.`

At the command line I enter

```bash
protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative\ --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \internal/protofiles/chat
.proto
```

I get an error -

```bash
No such file or directory.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Studying gRPC in golang

Comment: It's unclear but I suspect you're including the back-slashes (\\) in the command because originally the command was used for Linux where back-slashes are used for line continuation. Remove the back-slashes from the command and try again.

Answer (score 0):

protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative 
chat.proto

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is, what you're changing, and/or how your changes fix the problem?

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).